# RAW10 to RGB888 conversion

Tags: rgb, raw

I was using one omnivision sensor. I found it displays RAW10 output format.I want to convert it to RGB888. My doubt is since every 4 pixel has 5 byte information. The first byte will have P0[9:2] with this how can i have my RGB value.

hi i read somewhere we can just left out the 5th byte
so does it means that the 4 pixel will have one pixel rgb or what also
if the first pixel has RGB value how it can have only 8 bits since 24 bits will be required for that and if not then how we can convert it

Comment: Typical 1-chip color image sensors have [Bayer filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayer_filter)
on each pixel. In other words, each pixel has only one color (either of R, G, or B). You first need to interpolate pixel values with a processing called as `demosaic` or `debayer` to reproduce RGB values on each pixel position.